# updating the data with new field impacting lastmodifiedby and salesforce internal error

Tags: apex, custom-field, developer-console

I have the ContentVersion object, where I have a custom field called Year__c, which was initially set as text but I need to change it to a number field. but If I change it to number field, Salesforce says I will lose all the data in it. But I have some 7000 records in ContentVersion and that field is being referred in some custom code as well.

So, I created another field called Period_Year__c and had the same Label 'Year' and using developer console I wrote the following script to populate the data from year__c to Period_Year__c.

> Problem 1:- If I dont give the limit 1000, its throwing some
>   salesforce internal error, not sure why. So am giving limit 1000 and
>   running it 4 or 5 times to ensure all the data are copied.

```
List<ContentVersion> lstContent = [SELECT Id, Year__c, Period_Year__c FROM ContentVersion where Year__c != '' and Year__c != null and Period_Year__c = null and islatest=true limit 1000];
    if (lstContent.size() > 0)
    {
        for(ContentVersion Content : lstContent)
        {
            content.Period_Year__c = Decimal.valueOf(content.Year__c);
        }
        update lstContent;
    }
```

> Problem 2 :- All the records are reflecting with LastModifiedBy as my name. I
>   know this is the expected behaviour. Is there anyway that I could
>   retain LastModifiedBy so that users doesnt get to know this change?

I hardly bother about Problem 1 as that doesn't impact users but I really need an answer for my Problem 2.

Comment: Regarding #2, you can't bypass the Last Modified By field. There is a feature request for that (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqIjAAK).

Comment: Regarding #1, if you're getting an Internal Server Error, raise a case with technical support. They can help identify the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the info @sfdcfox but there are no other alternatives for my situation here right? :(

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a solution at this time.

Comment: oh okay!! Thanks for the info though!!

Comment: `content.Period_Year__c = Decimal.valueOf(content.Year__c);` Are you certain you want to use `Decimal.valueOf` as opposed to either `integer.valueOf` or get the `year` portion of `date.valueOf` instead? Not certain of correct syntax on last one right off the top of my head. `Decimal.valueOf` intuitively seems inappropriate to me for storing a year value.

Answer (score 1):

1 ->If this logic is written on a controller for a page and you're trying to display this list in a page, then there is a **governor limit of only 1000 records**, to avoid this use pagination. Also if you're using development mode in browser with View state enabled,then the Internal Server error is because you've exceeded the **View state limit of 135KB**. So please reduce the view state for the page.

2 -> If you want to modify the system fields like Created/Lastmodified fields, contact Salesforce.com to Enable this feature for you.Even after enabling this you cannot modify only one field,which is **systemModstamp**. For reference,view this link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm